# background drawable didn't stretch with text view width

Tags: android, tablelayout

Here is the problem: the text view border is smaller than the cell size in the column that contains "Looooooong Teeeeext"

[image]

I use this background drawable

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
   <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
   <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#1e11d5"/>
</shape>
```

and This layout for the table

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ll_country"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView11"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">
            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 >
            <LinearLayout 
                android:id="@+id/layout_table"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="5dip">
                <!-- <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:stretchColumns="0,1" android:id="@+id/country_table">
                </TableLayout> -->
            </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

this is the code that generates the table

```
for (int current = 0; current < 100 ; current++) {
            row = new TableRow(this);

            TextView t;
            for(int i =0 ; i < 20 ; i++){
                t = new TextView(this);
                t.setTextSize(20);
                t.setText(" text "+i+" ");
                t.setBackgroundDrawable(border);
                if((i== 4) && (current == 5)){
                    t.setText("  looooooong teeeeext  ");
                }
                //t.setWidth(20);
                t.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                row.addView(t,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                t.setBackgroundDrawable(border);
            }

            table.addView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        }

layout_table.addView(table, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you also show how you are generating the `border` drawable? I would suggest using

`t.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border)`

instead of

`t.setBackgroundDrawable(border)`

and see if this fixes the problem.

Comment: it worked. although i don't know the difference but many thanks

Comment: No problem. I'm assuming you probably created the Drawable once at a single size, and were then setting that same instance for all cells. Using the resource file would generate a correctly sized Drawable for each cell.